# Removing commas at the end of each new line in a string

Tags: python

Assume we have this following string called fruits:

```
Apple\n,
Orange\n,
Strawberry\n,
Banana\n,
Kiwi\n,
```

I want to remove all commas from each new line.

The results should look like this:

```
Apple\n
Orange\n
Strawberry\n
Banana\n
Kiwi\n
```

Here is my code so far but it is not working:

```
new_fruits = fruits.replace(',' '')
print(new_fruits)
```

Comment: To clarify does you string look like this? `fruits = "Apple\n,Orange\n, ... "`. 
Or are you loading from a text file?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you may be mixing syntax from other OO languages

This'll achieve what you're after:

```
new_fruits = fruits.replace(',', '')

print(new_fruits)
```

[Here're the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) on using `replace`

Edit to your edit: you're now just missing the comma between the arguments to `.replace` :)